# I have an alert prompt string written on Wordpress JS file but where is the info stored after they answer the popup?

Tags: javascript, wordpress

1.) I have an alert and prompt string written on my Wordpress Javascript file but where is the users information stored after they answer the popup question?

```
alert("Hello " + prompt("What is your name"));
```

The Javascript shows up running on here : http://izaguirre.me/contact/

My other questions are :

2.) Why does this javascript function only run on this page http://izaguirre.me/contact/ ?
Is there a way to add something to dictate which pages the prompt is supposed to run on ?

3.) Someone on another forum told me "its stored in javascript memory so no real way to 'see' it.  "

If what they said is completely true then whats the point of having someone type there name or information if its going to be erased as soon as they close the pop-up box? is it just for a temporary welcome message ?

Comment: Thank you , ok I will continue to learn, I was just confused but I guess its purpose was just a starting point not to be used as an actual useful string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript is client side, therefore the information does not get stored anywhere other than the user's browser. You need to use a server-side language, such as PHP if you want to store it on your server.

Currently, the JavaScript will only remain in the memory until they refresh or leave the page. For example, the JavaScript can validate a form by making sure that all the input fields are less than 5000 characters, that the user entered a valid looking email address, that the user filled out all the required fields. But JavaScript does not send the form or save the information or send the information to you (the server). The form is sent with PHP, and the text that the client writes is then often stored in a database such as mySQL.

Comment: "JavaScript is client side, therefore the information does not get stored anywhere other than the user's browser." Wow thank you so much , that just made me understand it alot more, I see now the point like you said its useful in letting the user know if they missed something on a form for example.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to change your code if you want to get the name variable.

```
var name = prompt("Please enter your name");

if (person != null) {
     alert("Hello " + name);
}
```

The person on the forum was correct, it is temporary. There is hardly a point to it.

Comment: Thank you for your help, if this string  is temporary and no real point then what is the difference with your code and adding a var, (im new to java) , what difference does that make

Comment: It is to temporarily get information from the user, you could use it to make a calculation, change the webpage, or anything related to js. It has its uses but if you cannot see its uses it's what you're looking for. P.S. You're new to javascript, not java... well maybe java too